# in_array problem with $GLOBALS

Tags: php, arrays, global

I have a `$GLOBALS['plugins']` array. With these values:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => calendarFuncs/
        [1] => calendar.php 
        [2] => Calendar
    )
    [1] => Array
    ( 
        [0] => eventFuncs/ 
        [1] => todo.php 
        [2] => Projects
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => financeFuncs/ 
        [1] => finance.php 
        [2] => Finances 
    )
    [3] => Array
    ( 
        [0] => crmFuncs/ 
        [1] => crm.php 
        [2] => CRM
    )
    [4] => Array
    ( 
        [0] => adminFuncs/ 
        [1] => admin.php 
        [2] => Admin
    )
)
```

This returns false, always...

```
in_array('Projects', $GLOBALS['plugins'])
```

Any thoughts?

Thank you.

Comment: Readable formatting would seriously increase the possibility of an answer.

Comment: Is that the output of `print_r($GLOBALS['plugins'])`? Because `$GLOBALS` isn't numerically indexed.

Comment: yes, that it is. print_r($GLOBALS['plugins'])

Comment: This is really strange. It should give a notice saying he can't find the 'plugins' key...

Comment: @greg0ire: I fixed the question to make it clear what that array is.

Comment: @BoltClock's a Unicorn: Good guess!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`in_array()` doesn't search recursively through multidimensional arrays.

You could loop through the `$GLOBALS['plugins']` array and do `in_array()` on each item inside instead.